# How to remove the dotted line in begining and in between of the text like as in the image?

Tags: html, css

How to remove the dotted line in begining and inbetween of the text like as in the image ?

[image]

my code
[codepen link](http://codepen.io/nikhilrajnair/pen/RrJgjj)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row menu-items">
      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: .menu-item .dotted-bg remove broder-top from it.

Comment: by doing this entire dotted lines get removed !

Comment: sorry for it. Now I understand your question.

Comment: it works by changing the code as 
.menu-item .dotted-bg{ border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 15px; 
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This my suggestion, use this

```
.menu-item .dotted-bg {
border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 15px; 
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Hi Just remove all line's. Add this two line

```
.menu-item .dotted-bg {
   border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
   margin-top:13px;
}
```

Comment: yeah it works in codepen ,let me try on local machine :)

Answer (score 0):

> Here what i did with your code is:

Just modified your CSS:

**Before:**

```
.menu-item .dotted-bg {
  border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**After:**

```
.menu-item .dotted-bg {
  border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Have , its' position as Relative; as if you put it as " Absolute " , it will be placed anywhere inside the div and it won't get set properly.

Hope this helps you.

```css
 .clearfix menu-wrapper {
  border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  }
.menu-item .price {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: right;
  font-family: Josefin Sans;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 19.8px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.menu-item h4 {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu-item {
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  margin: 15px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.menu-items{
  position: relative; height: 477.583px;
}
.menu-item .dotted-bg {
  border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfilo</title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row menu-items">
      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .clearfix menu-wrapper {
  border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  }
.menu-item .price {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: right;
  font-family: Josefin Sans;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 19.8px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.menu-item h4 {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu-item {
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  margin: 15px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.menu-items{
  position: relative; height: 477.583px;
}
.menu-item .dotted-bg {
  border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Portfilo</title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row menu-items">
      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clearfix menu-wrapper">      
          <h4>English asparagus</h4>
          <span class="price">$14.95</span>
          <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p>pellentesque enim. Aliquam tempor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```